# Django annotation output_field=DecimalField ignores max_digits and decimal_places

Tags: mysql, django, annotations

Inside an annotation I do some calculations, and I want the output to be a decimal, with max 8 digits and max 2 decimal. I don't know why but Django ignores decimal_places and max_digits.
Here is my code:

```
Order.objects.all().annotate(
        amount=Coalesce(
            Sum(
                Case(
                    When(
                        Q(payments__status='complete'),
                        then=F('payments__amount') - (
                            F('payments__amount') * F('payments__vat')/100
                        ) 
                    ), output_field=DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=8)

                )
            ), 0)
    ).values('amount')
```

output = `12.5999999999999996447286321199499070644378662109375`
I'm using Django 1.9.5

Comment: Try to use the `output_field` `arg` on the most outer level function i.e. `Coalesce` or try to use [Cast](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/database-functions/#cast)

Comment: on the most outer level - Not working.
 
Cast - is from Django 1.10, in 1.9.5 doesn't exist, i will try to upgrade to 1.10.5

Comment: @Todor
I made the upgrade to 1.10.5, half of my app is down, but when I use Cast, i get ```"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'numeric(None, None)) AS `amount` FROM `order` LEFT OUTER JOIN `' at line 1"```
Using 1.10 doesn't do the trick for me, any workarounds in 1.9.5?
I will wait for 1.11 stable which is LTS to upgrade

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had had the same issue in my job, to solve this I've created the following custom aggregate:

```
class SumDecimal(Func):
    function = 'SUM'
    name = 'sum'
    contains_aggregate = True
    output_field = DecimalField()
    template = '%(function)s(%(expressions)s)'

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.decimal_places = kwargs.pop('decimal_places', None)
        super(SumDecimal, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def as_sql(self, compiler, connection, function=None, template=None):
        sql = super(SumDecimal, self).as_sql(
            compiler=compiler,
            connection=connection,
            function=function,
            template=template)

        if self.decimal_places:
            sql, params = sql
            sql = 'CAST(%s AS DECIMAL(16, %d))' % (sql, self.decimal_places)
            return sql, params

        return sql
```

To use this is pretty simple, just use like:

```
mymodel.objects.all().annotate(sum_value=SumDecimal('value', decimal_places=2))
```

Comment: isn't Django has a better way